# jquery display + delay strategy

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following javascript displays the final result (instead of updating every second).  How can I iterate through the result of the getJSON call, display that result, and delay until I display the next element?

```
function display(state) {
  for (var i=0; i < state.length; i++) {
    $('#someDiv' + i).text(state[i]);
  }
}

$.getJSON('/getdata', function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    setTimeout(function(){display(val)}, 1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout`. Lose that abominable `sleep` function.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, because it was not appropriate to replace the non-working code from your original question with the solution. If you have a solution you're happy with that is different to the answers already posted then post it as an answer yourself and accept it. (Otherwise your question makes no sense because it is asking what is wrong with code that has nothing wrong with it.)

Comment: Actually, even his revised version would simply do all of the displays at once after 1 second.

Comment: Meant to originally write the edit which, as GoldenNewby commented, does not work as well.

Comment: That's nice and all, but you are changing the question making our answers useless. Your problem now is that you need to multiply the 1000 value in your setTimeout by iteration you are currently on (the key variable). So change the 1000 to 1000 * key

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the updated version carefully enough before rolling it back - I admit I was peeved because the edit appeared to make my original answer obsolete. I've updated my answer to match your updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your `$.each()` loop you queue all the timeouts at once, all for 1000ms after the loop. The simplest way to fix that is as follows:

```
$.getJSON('/getdata', function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    setTimeout(function(){display(val)}, 1000 * key);
  });
});
```

Noting that that will only work if `data` is an array and thus `key` is the integer index. If `data` is an object and `key` is not an integer index you could do this:

```
$.getJSON('/getdata', function(data) {
  var i = 0;
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    setTimeout(function(){display(val)}, 1000 * i++);
  });
});
```

(Set `i` to 1 initially if you don't want the first update to happen immediately.)